# nodejs v.0.8.2 cluster TypeError Object is not a function

Tags: node.js

i am trying to use node.js v0.8.2 and the cluster functionality to set up a web server on each core of my quad core machine

however i am stuck on a TypeError: Object is not a function, i am sure this is a simple error.

what am i doing wrong.

this is the code i am using

```
var cluster = require('cluster')
  , http = require('http');
```

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
  var body = 'Hello World';
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': body.length });
  res.end(body);
});

cluster(server)
  .use(cluster.logger('logs'))
  .use(cluster.stats())
  .use(cluster.pidfiles('pids'))
  .use(cluster.cli())
  .use(cluster.repl(8888))
  .listen(3000);

this is the erorr

```
F:\nodeJS\module\one.js:11
cluster(server)
^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object. (F:\nodeJS\module\one.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are over-complicating the use of cluster... try this instead:

```
var cluster = require('cluster')

if ( cluster.isMaster ) {
    for ( var i=0; i<2; ++i )
    cluster.fork();
} else {
    // includes for your app and app controller logic here  (just example using express, etc)
    ///////////////////
    // Server initiation
    ///////////////////
    var app = require('express').createServer(),
         redis = require("redis"), 
         Step = require("step"), 
         client = redis.createClient(siteConf.redisPort, siteConf.redisHost);

    // rest of your app here
}
```

Comment: this is on my Macbook Pro but on server with quad cores, I may fork up to 8 instances given the 8 cpu.

Comment: cheers mike i had that working for node v6, however when i upgraded to v8 only one of the 4 cores ever did any work, that "over complicated" came from node js samples, surely that must work?. I am using node v8 on windows 7, could that be a problem?, 64 bit

Comment: your comment is unclear.  did it solve your issue using my code instead?  I know mine works fine on Linux and on Mac but don't have Windows to test.  It should work fine on Win too.

Comment: the sequence of events that caused me to ask this question... first used cluster as you suggest with node v6 on 32 bit machine worked as exepected and all four cores participated. then upgraded to node v8 on 32 bit and only one of 4 cores ever did any work, this was still with code as you suggest. then changed my code to that in my original question and i get TypeError. i did use npm install cluster for all attempts though! i didnt realise cluster was a "builtin" part of node now, that must be my problem, havent had time to prove it though

Comment: in the code I suggested, did you change the integer value "2" to the number of CPUs on your server as I noted in my original comment?  There is another lib you can import to get CPUs dynamically but I find that waste so I just set the number manually.  The for ( var i=0; i<2; ++i )  is because on my macbook pro i only fork 2 instances but I would set i<8 on a quad core server.

Comment: Your old code is likely from old library thus the errors after upgrading versions.  Now the cluster module is this:  http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html

Comment: yes i have got further now, i get number of cores by <pre><code>var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;</pre></code>. i still cant seem to get all my four cores to do an equal amount of work. i am not certain if thats because i am not generating enough traffic or cluster module doesnt loadbalance very well. thanks for your time in responding to my question. i am still very new to both node and event programming.

Comment: no problem.  SO has been helpful for me in past and present to happy to contribute.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to use the old [Cluster module from LearnBoost](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/). Since that module was released, `cluster` is now the name of [a core module in Node.js](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html), and using `require('cluster')` will always return the core module. See [LearnBoost/cluster issue #166](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster/issues/166) for more information.